# Proof verification: For any function $f:A\rightarrow B$ there exists a function $g:B \rightarrow A$ so that $g \circ f=I_A$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Statement: For any function $f:A\rightarrow B$ there exists a function $g:B \rightarrow A$ so that $g \circ f=I_A$

My proof:

Negation: There exists a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ so that for all functions $g: B \rightarrow A$, $g \circ f \neq I_A$

Choose $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{3\}$. Choose $f: A \rightarrow B$ defined as $f(1)=3$, $f(2)=3$.

$$g \circ f(1)=g(f(1))=g(3)=g(3)=g(f(2))=g \circ f(2)$$

so $g \circ f(1)= g \circ f(2)$

This is where i'm not sure how to finish the proof. Is it valid to state that $I_A(1) \neq I_A(2)$ so therefore $g \circ f \neq I_A$? Do I use contradiction? or is there a better way of proving this?

Comment: As you perhaps already suspect, the statement that opens your Question is false.  So it makes no sense to ask for verification of a proof of that.  Likely you want to show the statement is false, but your presentation is not clear as to what you are trying to prove (is it the statement, or is it your "negation" of that statement?).  Please frame the problem you want help with more clearly, and if you don't see how to prove something, don't say you want "verification" of the nonexistent proof.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  You appear to have constructed a perfectly valid counterexample to the original claim.  That is enough to show that the original claim is false.  What else do you want to know?

Comment: Is $f$ supposed to be one-to-one?

Comment: Any **injective** function with nonempty domain has a left inverse. A non-injective function will never have a left inverse.